# Is there any difference of precision in python methods to calculate euclidean distance?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, euclidean-distance

I am calculating euclidean distance array by array in a numpy array. I was using `np.linalg.norm(v1-v2)` to this. Since I was planning to use other distance measures I changed that to `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(v1,v2)` to keep a pattern in my code.

I noticed the last digits vary a bit in each scenario. I thouth it wouldn't since scipy euclidean version uses functions from numpy core like `dot` and `sqrt`. I tried other ways in Python to calculate euclidean distance to compare and for a specific example I got these results.

```
>>> math.sqrt(sum([(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(v1,v2)]))
1.0065822095995844
>>> numpy.linalg.norm(v1-v2)
1.0065822095995838
>>> sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances(v1.reshape(1,-1),v2.reshape(1,-1))[0,0]
1.0065822095995838
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(v1,v2)
1.006582209599584
```

Just for the record, in my examples, v1 and v2 are normalized histograms.
Why is there this difference in precision? Should this happen?

Comment: Could be in part due to different summation algorithms. I think `numpy` uses [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation), not sure about the default python `sum` and `sklearn`.

Comment: Interesting. But even though, if `numpy` uses pairwise summation and `scipy` uses `numpy` core functions, so the results would be the same, right? Why not?

Comment: Looking at the source, `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` calls `minkowski`, which calls `scipy.linalg.norm` and finally the blas function `nrm2` (might depend on scipy version). This is different from `numpy`. Broadly, I think receiving slightly different floating point output from these implementations seems normal.

Comment: I'm inclined to think of this question as a special case of a general question about the inconsistency of floating point calculations. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a slightly heavy but very thorough discussion. But the TLDR is that in floating point arithmetic, different ways of calculating the same values will _frequently_ give slightly different (but very close) results.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are stored in computer as a fraction, with 53 bits to represent the numerator. So you cannot get a floating point answer with more than 15 significant digits of precision.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html